# How to fix SSRS 2012 with report viewer 11, parameter is missing a value?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two reports:

1. Report1: asks for a year, links to Report2.
2. Report2: shows some information.

I load Report1 (asks for a year), then go to Report2 through the link in Report1, hit browser back button, it takes me to report list home page, hit forward browser button, takes me to Report1 but before loading (as in asks for a year again), I enter a year and press View Report, and I get the error "The 'ID' parameter is missing a value".

Some things to note:

- Error only happens in C# app using ReportViewer in the following browsers: Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi.
- Firefox works perfectly. IE and Edge show "Page has expired" after hitting the back button (which is better in my opinion).
- Error does not happen when browsing the reports on the report server Web Portal URL.
- The 'ID' parameter is a hidden parameter in Report2. Available Values is none.

Has something like this happened to anyone else? How could I fix it, or where can I start searching for a fix?

Comment: Why do you need to do like that, go _back and forth_ with the browser button ?

Comment: You can use the "Go to Report" actions in the report. This allows you to pass parameters back and forth. Also, you should use the back and forward buttons on the Report Viewer Control, not the browser.

Comment: I do not _need_ to do it, but users do, and for them it is a bug to be fixed. How can I use the "Go to Report" actions to pass parameters while using the browser back button? Where can I find more information about your suggestion?